# How to add "collection" field to metadata for Solana NFTs with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio, solana, nft

I'm trying to add the collection field (name and family) to my metadata using VSC. Not sure where to begin or how to do it. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
{
  "name": "Solflare X NFT",
  "symbol": "",
  "description": "Celebratory Solflare NFT for the Solflare X launch",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
  "image": "https://www.arweave.net/abcd5678?ext=png",
  "animation_url": "https://www.arweave.net/efgh1234?ext=mp4",
  "external_url": "https://solflare.com",
  "attributes": [
    { "trait_type": "web", "value": "yes" },
    { "trait_type": "mobile", "value": "yes" },
    { "trait_type": "extension", "value": "yes" }
  ],
  "collection": { "name": "Solflare X NFT", "family": "Solflare" },
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/abcd5678?ext=png",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://watch.videodelivery.net/9876jkl",
        "type": "unknown",
        "cdn": true
      },
      { "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/efgh1234?ext=mp4", "type": "video/mp4" }
    ],
    "category": "video",
    "creators": [
      { "address": "SOLFLR15asd9d21325bsadythp547912501b", "share": 100 }
    ]
  }
}
```